# VSTS Unit test - build system

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, msbuild

I have developed a build system on MSBuild (NET 3.0) and cc.net to perform continuous integration builds of a Visual Studio 2008 application, however a developer on the team recently added a VSTS unit test project to the mix.  Is there any SDK or add-in provided by microsoft to allow this to be compiled on a non-team system build environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the tests from the command-line, but it requires that the Test Edition of Visual Studio be installed on your build server:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/09/25/clean-build-server-with-mstest-fail.aspx

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2008/03/18/Continuous-Integration-Setup-with-MSTest.aspx

This person is doing MSTest with CC.NET, so it might be helpful:

http://testearly.findtechblogs.com/default.asp?item=630602

In general, this is a main reason why many people choose something like [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org), [xUnit.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) or [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) over MSTest.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like I'll have to track down a copy of test edition.

Comment: Just a small correction, in 2008 you can get away with the Profession version of Visual Studio if you just want to run unit tests on a build server.  You'll need the Test Edition of VSTS if you want to publish the test results back into TFS.  Still a long way from clean build server though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSTEST You will have to put that edition on the build server. To cut a long story short youd be better off changing the testing framework the developer is using from MStest to Nunit.
Its a much lighter solution.